# MirrorMaker2.0 Not replicating

Tags: apache-kafka, tibco, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am configuring MirrorMaker2.0 and it is not replicating. I have 2 clusters with 4 servers per cluster. Broker and Zookeeper are running on all the servers. From what I understand I only need to configure and run mirrormaker2.0 on 1 server per cluster.

- mirrormaker.properties file is identical on A_host1:9094 and B_host1:9094
- mirrormaker2.0 is running on A_host1:9094 and B_host1:9094
- broker and zookeeper is up
- Running on Tibco Kafka 3.2.0

This is my mirrormaker.properties file.

```
# connection information for each cluster
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs for each cluster
# for e.g. "A_host1:9092, A_host2:9092, A_host3:9092"
 
Source.bootstrap.servers = A_host1:9094, A_host2:9094, A_host3:9094, A_host4:9094
Target.bootstrap.servers = B_host1:9094, B_host2:9094, B_host3:9094, B_host4:9094
 
# enable and configure individual replication flows
Source->Target.enabled = true
 
# regex which defines which topics gets replicated. For eg "foo-.*"
Source->Target.topics = .*
 
Target->Source.enabled = true
Target->Source.topics = .*
groups = .*
# Setting replication factor of newly created remote topics
replication.factor=4
 
############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for mm2 internal topics "heartbeats", "B.checkpoints.internal" and
# "mm2-offset-syncs.B.internal"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 4.
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=4
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=4
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=4
 
# "mm2-status.B.internal"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 4.
offset.storage.replication.factor=4
status.storage.replication.factor=4
config.storage.replication.factor=4
 
# customize as needed
#replication.policy.separator = _
 
sync.topic.acls.enabled = true
sync.group.offsets.enabled = true
 
emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds = 5
emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds = 10
max.tasks = 5
refresh.topics.interval.seconds = 30
refresh.groups.interval.seconds = 30
```